# Joomla.32 SEF url and com_tags

Tags: joomla, tags, seo, joomla3.2, sef

I'm using Joomla v3.2
In the com_tags component I have modified the helpers/route.php file in order to include the catid and the Itemid in the url query. (The query is constructed by the module mod_easycloud which has been modified also).

```
$link = 'index.php?option=com_tags&view=tag&id=' .$id.'&Itemid='.JRequest::getInt('Itemid');
$link .= '&catId='.JRequest::getInt('catId');
```

I also modified the router.php file in order to build and parse the correct SEF url.

But when I'm switching to SEF urls, the **Itemid**  parameter does not work. The content is correctly linked with the category **catid**, but the current menu item is not active.

The functionality above is working when I switch back to non-sef urls.

Answer (score 0):

Try using JRoute::_( $link ).
This prepares the route to be used as a normal url and as a SEF url afaik.

Comment: using the JRoute::_( $link ) makes no difference.